# How to wrap group with groupid got in inner nesting of array of object

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js

i want to `wrap` group `span` with `groupid` got inside of array of objects

**Expected Output:**

```
<div id="wrapper">
   <span class="group-wrapper" data-groupid="3333333333333333">
      <p>Name : ABC</p>
      <p>Name : AABBCC</p>
   </span>
   <span class="group-wrapper" data-groupid="5555555555555555">
      <p>Name : DEF</p>
   </span>
   <span class="group-wrapper" data-groupid="7777777777777777">
      <p>Name : GHI</p>
   </span>
</div>
```

**Note:**  observe `data-groupid` having value, but in my code i'm unable to get it. **(i don't want any random value for `data-groupid`, i want exact value)**

**Note2:** i cannot change `json` **structure** as it is used my many applications(i don't have control)

**my code producing:**

```
<div id="wrapper">
   <span class="group-wrapper" data-groupid="">
      <p>Name : ABC</p>
   </span>
   <span class="group-wrapper" data-groupid="">
      <p>Name : DEF</p>
   </span>
   <span class="group-wrapper" data-groupid="">
      <p>Name : GHI</p>
   </span>
</div>
```

**here is demo:**

```js
var array = [
   {"list":[{"id":"3333333333333333","name":"ABC"},{"id":"3333333333333333","name":"AABBCC"}]},
   {"list":[{"id":"5555555555555555","name":"DEF"}]},
   {"list":[{"id":"7777777777777777","name":"GHI"}]},
];

var fullHtmlStr = '', groupStr = '';
for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
   var tempGroupWrapper = '<span class="group-wrapper" data-groupid="">';
   var list = array[i].list;
   for(j = 0; j < list.length; j++){
      var item = list[j];
      console.log(item);
      fullHtmlStr = '<p>Name : '+item.name+'</p>';
      tempGroupWrapper += fullHtmlStr;
   }
   tempGroupWrapper += '</span>';
   groupStr += tempGroupWrapper;
}

console.log(groupStr);

$('#wrapper').html(groupStr);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="wrapper">

</div>
```

Comment: **Edited my Question** please see my **Expected Output**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this?
I moved `tempGroupWrapper` into the loop and put `item.id` inside the `groupid`.

```js
var array = [
   {"list":[{"id":"3333333333333333","name":"ABC"},{"id":"3333333333333333","name":"AABBCC"}]},
   {"list":[{"id":"5555555555555555","name":"DEF"}]},
   {"list":[{"id":"7777777777777777","name":"GHI"}]},
];

var groupStr = '';
for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
   var fullHtmlStr = '';
   var list = array[i].list;
   for(var j = 0; j < list.length; j++){
      var item = list[j];
      console.log(item);
      fullHtmlStr += '<p>Name : '+item.name+'</p>';
   }
   var tempGroupWrapper = '<span class="group-wrapper" data-groupid="' + item.id + '">';
   tempGroupWrapper += fullHtmlStr + '</span>';
   groupStr += tempGroupWrapper;
}

console.log(groupStr);

$('#wrapper').html(groupStr);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="wrapper">

</div>
```

Comment: Oh my  God , so simple is the solution , i was not knowing

Comment: BUt it does not work for list multiple values `{"list":[{"id":"3333333333333333","name":"ABC"},{"id":"3AAAAAAAA","name":"AABBCC"}]}`

Comment: Edited my Question please see that

Comment: What would be the expected output?

Comment: Edited my question, see **Expected Output**

Comment: Updated. Test it again.